# Spring запускает пустой html файл или thymeleaf не работает

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с классами контроллерами и моделями все в порядке, в базе данных есть данные о человеке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

проект билдится без ошибок но выдает пустую html страницу при переходе на people, но не выдает пустую страницу например при переходе на people/new

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете шаблонизатор, то спринг автоматически меняет место поиска представлений.

> ["By default, Spring Boot looks for our templates in src/main/resources/templates. We can put our templates there and organize them in sub-directories and have no issues"](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-template-directory)

Попробуйте файлы представлений положить в папку `src/main/resources/templates`. Папку `templates` нужно создать самостоятельно.
Будет примерно так: `src/main/resources/templates/books/edit.html`

И в контроллере возвращайте логическое имя представления:
`return "books/edit";`

Спринг автоматом допишет к этой строке префикс `"src/main/resources/templates/"` и строку `".html"` добавит с конца.